# Indcredible mistake ent.SuperStudentEntity cannot be cast ent.SuperStudentEntity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Hibernate+Spring Boot

i can not get object

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/get/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
SuperStudentEntity getById(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
return new StudentDAOImpl().getById(id);
}
```

DAO function

```
public SuperStudentEntity getById(int id){
openTransactionSession();

Session s = getSession();

String sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id_student =:id";
org.hibernate.query.Query query = s.createNativeQuery(sql).addEntity(SuperStudentEntity.class);
query.setParameter("id",id);

SuperStudentEntity student  = (SuperStudentEntity) query.getSingleResult();

closeTransactionSesstion();

return student;
}
```

And get exceptions

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.codexample.ent.SuperStudentEntity cannot be cast to org.codexample.ent.SuperStudentEntity
at org.codexample.impldao.StudentDAOImpl.getById(StudentDAOImpl.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
at org.codexample.controllers.StudentController.getById(StudentController.java:54) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at ....
```

And browser tell me :

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu May 18 20:02:30 MSK 2017 There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500). org.codexample.ent.SuperStudentEntity cannot be cast to org.codexample.ent.SuperStudentEntity

I don't understand how resolve it problem.

Comment: Why are you even using a SQL query? Use a HQL query or even better just use `get` and the `Session` instance, something like `return s.get(SuperStudentEntity.class, id);` and remove all of the other stuff.

Comment: @M. Denium , but your code is wrong too :( . I don't understand how solve it problem, but i can try use JDBC and my realization work  well with JDBC. I think something wrong in Hibernate...

Comment: Well I doubt there is something wrong with hibernate... I suspect it has to do on how you are doing things. You are using Spring and Spring Boot but your code is heavily not geared towards that, you are creating new instances of beans yourself (where you should inject them), you are opening session yourself (where you shouldn't) so I would first start and try to improve/cleanup your overal code (and might I suggest to use JPA instead of plain hibernate).